# linux kernel-device tree-pass data from parent to child

Tags: c, linux, device-tree

I am interested in passing some data (dynamically created at run time) from a parent node to a child node in the device tree. For instance, I have the following entry in the device tree:

```
parent_node {
    a-string-property = "A string";
    a-string-list-property = "first string", "second string";
    a-byte-data-property = [0x01 0x23 0x34 0x56];
    child-node1 {
        first-child-property;
        second-child-property = <1>;
        a-string-property = "Hello, world";
    };
    child-node2 {
      some_data ;
    };
};
```

As far as I know, you cannot create/update properties of a device tree node at runtime (correct?).

So is there any kind of mechanism to pass data between parent node and child node (maybe through `struct bus_type`, `struct device` or 
`struct device_driver`)?

The final purpose of this data passing is to provide an offset for address translation of devices' memory mappings (child nodes).

Comment: Do you have an example for "*pass data between parent node and child node*"?

Comment: If I have had an example,I wouldn't ask :)

Comment: "pass data from parent to child" is too vague. There are many ways to pass data around. Could you be more specific, please? What sub-system are you talking about (clock, sound, ...)? Please describe the use-case.

Answer (score 0):

> you cannot create/update properties of device tree node at runtime (correct?).

On some platforms, the device tree can be manipulated at runtime. 
See the `CONFIG_OF_DYNAMIC` configuration item.

[Here](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/dynamic-dt-elce14.pdf) is a presentation about dynamic dt.

The platforms **sparc** and **powerpc** [seem to have](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=of_set_property) the following function for this purpose:

```
int of_set_property(struct device_node *dp, const char *name, void *val, int len)
```

Comment: You are correct - sparc architecture does have this feature,unsure about power pc .But ,unfortunately,my architecture is ARM ,therefore this path is irrelevant.Can anyone suggest something involving some bus structure (just a walkthrough would be okay,no code necessary :) )